# explicit wait different forms

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I wrote explicit wait 2 ways to do the same task but one of them is not working. the one which isn't working is from the tutorials I have been following to learn Automated Testing. I want to know what is wrong with the second code.

**working code:**

```
IWebElement wait2 = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.Id("finish")));
```

**Not working**

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
IWebElement ele = wait.Until((result) => {
        return result.FindElement(By.Id("finish"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You were close enough. Using the *lambda* expression you can use the following solution:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
IWebElement ele = wait.Until(result => result.FindElement(By.Id("finish")));
```

In a single line:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(result => result.FindElement(By.Id("finish")));
```

Comment: for some reason only a single line solution is working. for the other one, test finishes even before the elements on the page are loaded.

Comment: @WaseemAbbas Whats's wrong with a single line solution?